# WFS Filter inside WPS request

Tags: geoserver, wfs, wps

Depending on [this](https://wiki.state.ma.us/display/massgis/GeoServer+-+WPS+-+Nearest) example

I've created the following WPS request to get the nearst airport from a given point.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wps:Execute version="1.0.0" service="WPS" xmlns:tst="tst" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0" xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs" xmlns:wps="http://www.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0" xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:wcs="http://www.opengis.net/wcs/1.1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0 http://schemas.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0/wpsAll.xsd">
  <ows:Identifier>gs:Nearest</ows:Identifier>
  <wps:DataInputs>
    <wps:Input>
      <ows:Identifier>features</ows:Identifier>
      <wps:Reference mimeType="text/xml; subtype=wfs-collection/1.0" xlink:href="http://geoserver/wfs" method="POST">
        <wps:Body>
          <wfs:GetFeature service="WFS" version="1.0.0" outputFormat="GML2">
            <wfs:Query typeName="tst:ne_10m_airports"/>
                 <ogc:Filter>
                     <ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThan>
                          <ogc:PropertyName>scalerank</ogc:PropertyName>
                          <ogc:Literal>5</ogc:Literal>
                     </ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThan>
                 </ogc:Filter>
          </wfs:GetFeature>
        </wps:Body>
      </wps:Reference>
    </wps:Input>
    <wps:Input>
      <ows:Identifier>point</ows:Identifier>
      <wps:Data>
        <wps:ComplexData mimeType="application/json">
        <![CDATA[
        {
          "type": "Point",
          "coordinates": [
              21.5,
              15.5
          ]
        }
        ]]>
      </wps:ComplexData>
      </wps:Data>
    </wps:Input>
    <wps:Input>
      <ows:Identifier>crs</ows:Identifier>
      <wps:Data>
        <wps:LiteralData>EPSG:4326</wps:LiteralData>
      </wps:Data>
    </wps:Input>
  </wps:DataInputs>
  <wps:ResponseForm>
    <wps:RawDataOutput mimeType="application/json">
      <ows:Identifier>result</ows:Identifier>
    </wps:RawDataOutput>
  </wps:ResponseForm>
</wps:Execute>
```

The filter inside the WFS:Query is not executed, although I put a criteria scalerank > 5, the WPS request returns an airport with scalerank = 4 !!

What am I missing or doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your request isn't valid, the query must contain the filter.

```
     <wfs:GetFeature service="WFS" version="1.0.0" outputFormat="GML2">
     <wfs:Query typeName="tst:ne_10m_airports">
             <ogc:Filter>
                 <ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThan>
                      <ogc:PropertyName>scalerank</ogc:PropertyName>
                      <ogc:Literal>5</ogc:Literal>
                 </ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThan>
             </ogc:Filter>
      </wfs:Query>
      </wfs:GetFeature>
```

Comment: This is a great answer, because the WPS Request builder in Geoserver doesn't seem to allow putting the filter in the query. This process implies the filter is in a separate parameter to the process